# Apache Redirect URL with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all traffic from one domain to a specific page, with parameter, on a different domain.  For example, all these URL's should redirect to the same URL:

http://domain_1.com  (and all subdirectories)

eg. http://domain_1.com/sub/page.php etc.

should redirect to:

http://domain_2.com/newpage.php?name=parameter

This is what I have. How do I get the QUERY_STRING to be part of the redirect? (name=parameter does not change)

```
RewriteEngineOn
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}% name=parameter
RedirectMatch / http://domain_2.com/newpage.php
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Don't mix mod-alias with mod-rewrite these are two diffrent modules.

Comment: starkeen, are you saying that what I'm trying to do is not possible?

Comment: What is supposed to be the value of "name=parameter"? Your question is unclear.

Comment: For example: host=domain_1.com